# How can I change the terminal tmux info (lower right) called status-right to username or host?

Tags: tmux

I have 7 dashes (`-------`) on the lower right.
Can I replace them with something like my name or my host name?

This is not about the PS1 prompt.  I already have time name host dir there.
I use tmux.
I am on Ubuntu13 but I'd like it to work in iterm2 on OSX if possible.

In `.tmux.conf` I have it as

```
set -g status-right "-------"
```

How can I make it be user or host?  I tried \u but that didn't work.

Example:

[image]**<--- here**

Comment: Post your `tmux.conf`: that is normally the area defined by `status-right`...

Comment: On second thoughts, this *does* look like it is about your (possibly broken) PS1. Is that dotted line supposed to be above every prompt?

Comment: +1, nope you got it the first time, it's my `.tmux.conf` file setting for `status-right`.  Updating the question with the new info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The FORMATS section of `man tmux` has a complete list of the values that you can use in your status line.

As well as these, you can pipe the output of shell commands, making it possible to include any information that is accessible from your shell in the status line.

Your hostname, for example, can be printed with `#H`, or `#h` for the short name (without the domain name).

To include your name (and not hardcode it), you could print the truncated output of `who`: which would be something like `#(who | cut -d \" \" -f1)`. Note that you need to escape the quotation marks...

I have a more comprehensive answer to this question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628435/tmux-status-bar-configuration/9630367#9630367)..

Comment: or just use 'whoami'

Answer (score 10):

To set hostname to right part of tmux statusbar:

```
set -g status-right "#H"
```

You can find more commands in this tmux cheatsheet under "Customizing tmux" section: http://www.cheatography.com/bechtold/cheat-sheets/tmux-the-terminal-multiplexer/